# How to remove the following warning Android Studio?

Tags: android

I must fix orientation of my screen in my Android app. But when I put the code

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

But this shows the error - 'You should not lock the orientation of your activities.....' ;
How can I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a warning, not an error - it flags potential issues but you can ignore it completely if you know what you are doing and that orientation related call is exactly what you want. In that case you can let Lint know that, by using `@SuppressLint` annotation, so it would stop complaining in future. See official docs: http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings